# Intuitive understanding of $g^iH=(gH)^i$ factor groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

I'm having trouble coming to grips with the fact that when dealing with the composition of cosets in a factor group, it will be true that $g^iH = (gH)^i$.  If I think about the rule that's actually given to me:

$$
(aH)(bH)=abH
$$

I'm quite happy with that.  If we're dealing with cyclic groups, I understand that given a cyclic group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ then the factor group should (more or less) be defind as the following:

$$
G/H=\{g^iH \mid i \in \mathbb{Z} \}
$$

I'm good with that also.  I just can't make whatever leap is necessary to understand the implication that $g^iH = (gH)^i$.  All of the insights I have seen are some derivative of, "it's given by the definition," which is not good enough.

For context, I am working through trying to prove that a factor group of a cyclic group is cyclic, and this seems to be what I need to make everything work.

I suspect that I am not thinking abstractly enough.  My brain keeps telling me to turn $(gH)^i$ into $g^iH^i$ which I don't think is a thing.  Apparently it's an easy enough induction proof, but I haven't seen one nor have I been able to construct one for the same reason.

Any insights will be appreciated.  Apologies if I've missed something blatantly obvious.

Comment: Even if you treat $gH$ as two objects, $(gH)^2$ is still $gHgH$ not $g^2 H^2$. (Although in this case $gHgH = ggHH$

Comment: It'd be best to write $gHgH=ggHH=g^2H$, which follows from $Hg=gH$ in the middle and $HH=H$ since $H$ is a subgroup. The notation $H^2$ could refer to the set of / subgroup generated by squares in $H$ in some contexts.

Comment: Yeah, this is where my hangup is...  The notation makes it seem like the subgroup is being composed, but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only prove the case for $i=2$. Prove the other cases by induction.

Let $a \in (gH)^2 = (gH)(gH)$, i.e. there is $b,c \in H$ such that $a = gbgc$. Then, $a = g^2 bc$ (cyclic group is abelian) and $bc \in H$, so $a \in g^2 H$.

Let $a \in g^2 H$, i.e. there is $b \in H$ such that $a=g^2b$, so $a = gegb$, so $a \in (gH)(gH)$.

Comment: I think this will make a great start.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $H^2 = H$, which is trivially true. Then:

$$(aH)(aH) = aHaH = aaH^2 = a^2H$$